# Show percentage and label

Tags: python, pyqt5, qchart

I'm trying to show the label and the percentage in the Qchart but it show me only one of them

Is there a way to show both of them

This is my function that run the QtChart

```
def charts_jr_acte(self):# pushButton_123

        

        rightseries = QPieSeries()


        rightseries.setLabelsVisible(True)
        rightseries.setLabelsPosition(QPieSlice.LabelInsideHorizontal)
        

        for C_acte, montant in rows:
            rightseries.append(C_acte, montant)
        
        slice = QPieSlice()
        slice = rightseries.slices() [2]
        slice.setExploded(True)
        slice.setPen(QtGui.QPen(Qt.darkBlue))

            
        for slice in rightseries.slices():
                slice.setLabel("{:.2f}%".format(100 * slice.percentage()))
        
        rightchart = QChart()
        rightchart.createDefaultAxes()
        rightchart.addSeries(rightseries)
        rightchart.setTitle("total journalier de chaque Acte")
        rightchart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)


        rightchart.legend().setVisible(True)
        rightchart.legend().setAlignment(Qt.AlignBottom)

        rightchart.legend().markers(rightseries)[1].setLabel(lab)

        rightseries.setLabelsVisible()
        rightseries.setLabelsPosition(QtChart.QPieSlice.LabelInsideHorizontal)

        self.graphicsView_4.setChart(rightchart)
```

`
and this is an example of the result

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i find a way to make it work

```
def charts_jr_acte(self):# pushButton_123

        

        rightseries = QPieSeries()


        rightseries.setLabelsVisible(True)

        for C_acte, montant in rows:
            rightseries.append(C_acte, montant)
        
        slice = QPieSlice()
        slice = rightseries.slices() [2]
        slice.setExploded(True)
        slice.setPen(QtGui.QPen(Qt.darkBlue))

            
        for slice in rightseries.slices():
            slice.setLabelVisible()
            oldLabel=slice.label()
            slice.setLabel((oldLabel+": %.1f%%"  %(slice.percentage()*100) ))
        
        rightchart = QChart()
        rightchart.createDefaultAxes()
        rightchart.addSeries(rightseries)
        rightchart.setTitle("total journalier de chaque Acte")
        rightchart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.SeriesAnimations)


        rightchart.legend().setVisible(True)


        self.graphicsView_4.setChart(rightchart)
```

this how it look like

[image]